# Make Parse5 case-sensitive

Tags: javascript, angular, abstract-syntax-tree

I've been trying to parse Angular Templates into AST using the [parse5](https://github.com/inikulin/parse5) lib, since it has everything I need. But there's a problem - when parsing HTML, it seems like the lib makes everything lowercase.

Example:

```js
 tagName: 'span',
  attrs: [
    { name: '*ngif', value: 'true' },
  ]
```

`*ngIf` has become `*ngif`. That of course is a problem

Is there a way to avoid this? To tell parse5 to not make everything lowercase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to make Parse5 case sensitive, since [it converts everything to lower case](https://github.com/inikulin/parse5/blob/v7.1.0/packages/parse5/lib/tokenizer/index.ts#L1763). But you can use [PostHTML](https://posthtml.org/#/) instead for this purpose, here is [playground](https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/4010a05f7ef364cd0136298390773945/54c9bba01b8234779d2bc3bfb579775418d22dee), so such code:

```js
<p *ngIf=true>My first paragraph.</p>
```

Can be converted to:

```js
<h2 *ngIf="true">My first paragraph.</h2>
```

With help of:

```js
export default function(tree) {
  tree.match({ tag: "p" }, node => {
    node.tag = 'h2';
    return node;
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, that's what I ended up doing. Parse5 is excellent, but it really sucks that it doesn't have such a simple option :/